# matplotlib (seaborn): plot correlations between one variable vs multiple others

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, correlation

When plotting correlations, this code

```
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> g = sns.pairplot(iris)
```

results in the following pairplot:

http://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/seaborn-pairplot-1.png

What if I just want to show the first row out of those four (i.e. correlations of 'sepal_length' vs all other features)? How can I plot that? Could pairplot be used but with some modifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `x_vars` and `y_vars` arguments of `pairplot` you can select which columns to correlate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g = sns.pairplot(iris, 
                 x_vars=["sepal_width","petal_length","petal_width"],
                 y_vars=["sepal_length"])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! :)